# lxml: Do not parse subtree but treat as binary content

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xslt, lxml

I am working on XML content that contains elements which may hold potentially malformed XML/markup-like (e.g. HTML) content as text. For example:

```
<root>
    <data>
        <x>foo<y>bar</y>
    </data>
    <data>
        <z>foo<y>bar</y>
    </data>
</root>
```

**Goal**: I want `lxml.etree` to not attempt to parse anything under `data`-elements as XML but rather simply return it as `bytes` or `str` (can be in `elem.text`).

The files are big and I wanted to use `lxml.etree.iterparse` to extract the contents found in `data`-
elements.

**Initial Idea**: A straightforward way to just get the contents of the element (in this case containing the `data` start- and end-tags) could be:

```
data = BytesIO(b"""
<root>
    <data>
        <x>foo<y>bar</y>
    </data>
    <data>
        <z>foo<y>bar</y>
    </data>
</root>
""")

from lxml import etree

# see below why html=True
context = etree.iterparse(data, events=("end",), tag=("data",), html=True)
contents = []  # I don't keep lists in the "real" application
for event, elem in context:
    contents.append(etree.tostring(elem))  # get back the full content underneath data
```

The **problem** with this is that `lxml.etree` can run into issues parsing the children of `data` (for example: I already had to use `html=True` to not run into issues when `html`-data is stored under `data`). I know that there are [custom element classes](https://lxml.de/element_classes.html) in `lxml` but from how I understand the documentation, they do not change `lxml.etree`'s parsing behaviour dictated by `libxml2`).

Is there any easy way to tell `lxml` to not attempt to parse element content as children. The application itself benefits from other `lxml` functionality which I would have to replicate if I wrote a custom extractor for `data` alone.

Or could there a way to use XSLT to first transform the input for processing in `lxml` and to later link back the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work as expected? 
The XML is modified by adding DTD and CDATA to specify that the content inside the data element has to be treated as character data.

```
data = io.BytesIO(B'''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE root [
<!ELEMENT root (data+)>
<!ELEMENT data (#PCDATA)>
]>

<root>
    <data>
        <![CDATA[
        <x>foo<y>bar</y>
        ]]>
    </data>
    <data>
        <![CDATA[
        <z>foo<y>bar</y>
        ]]>
    </data>
</root>

''')

from lxml import etree

# see below why html=True
context = etree.iterparse(data, events=("end",), tag=("data",), dtd_validation=True, load_dtd=True)
contents = []  # I don't keep lists in the "real" application
for event, elem in context:
    contents.append(etree.tostring(elem))  # get back the full content underneath data
```

Comment: thanks, that's an interesting idea. i am not well versed in XSLT, but will see if I can transfer the data so that the annotations are added accordingly and see whether this can solve the issue. I keep the question open until I have validated the appraoch.

Comment: If you think CDATA sections are a good idea, just use them. There is no need to add a DOCTYPE declaration for that.